# Why does linux show 2,31G of RAM when using mem=3780512k?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory

My system has 4G of RAM installed (2x2G). When I boot it normally, I get

```
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3780512 kB
```

Which is around 3,6G.

I want to configure [ramoops](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.2/admin-guide/ramoops.html) and I have to define the `mem=` kernel parameter, but no matter what I set in it, the available RAM is always capped to 2,31G. So if I set `mem=4096M` or `mem=3600M` or `mem=3072M`, it always be  `2,31G` . When I set `mem=2048M` , then I think it starts to work because `/proc/meminfo` shows `MemTotal` a little bit less than 2G.

So the question is why does it show `2,31G` , and how to set it so it would show ~3,6G?

```
# dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name
1439

# dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer
Hewlett-Packard
```

Actually it's a laptop HP G62. It has a GPU integrated into P6100 CPU. According to the `lspci -v`, it takes 256M of RAM, right?:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 3050 [size=8]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Do you know whether you are dealing with GB or GiB?  The memory you bought is likely 4 GB, i.e. 3.725 GiB (3815 MiB).

Comment: Can be 4GB, but still it is a way more than 2,3GB

Comment: @Kusalananda RAM is always sold in powers of two, so 4G is 4GiB.

Comment: @StephenKitt If you say so, I get mixed up with disk sizes, which I believe are sold using SI units. I'm also not really a hardware person :-)  However, `G` and `M` could mean anything, and `kB` is a non-standard unit no matter what way you look at it.

Comment: @Kusalananda yup, it’s all very confusing; disks are sold using SI units, RAM using IEC units, flash using SI units, network speeds are measured with 10-bit transfers...

Comment: Discrepancies between `mem=` settings and the available memory *should* be explainable using the kernel’s boot messages. How much memory is mapped by your PCI devices?

Comment: I don't know, how to check that? But still, without the `mem=` parameter it shows 3,6G, so why setting it to 3,6G results in 2,31G ?

Comment: @StephenKitt, 10-bit transfers?? Aren't they just bits per second?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, comms speeds are usually given in bits per second (and using SI units). My point was that converting those to bytes per second often involves taking into account 4-over-5 or 8-over-10 encoding.

Comment: @Mikhail `dmesg` will tell you what the kernel found, and `lspci -v` will tell you how much room is needed for PCI devices (which shouldn’t affect `mem=`, in theory, but IIRC there are situations where it does, and you need `memmap`).

Comment: @StephenKitt, hmm yeah, though that depends, if I read my sources right, e.g. Fast Ethernet uses 125 MHz symbol rate with 4b/5b encoding so the advertised 100 Mb/s is what you actual get (minus protocol overhead, of course). And AFAIU, Gigabit Ethernet also gives the advertised 1 Gb/s. Of course the encodings vary too, so it's not always 8/10 even if the advertised value is the encoded line-rate.

Comment: @ilkkachu yup, 100baseT and 1000baseT (except over twisted pair, IIRC) really do give you 100/8 and 1000/8 bytes per second respectively, at the physical layer. The issue crops up more in serial comms and things like ATM etc., so for example typical ADSL bandwidths convert to bytes-per-second using 10-bit bytes.

Comment: @K7AAY I added the output in question.

Comment: @K7AAY It's a laptop, see the question.

Comment: Your HP model G62 laptop https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02497777 has an integrated graphics adapter. It can be configured to take up to 1405 MB memory from the motherboard to use for graphics. How is it configured in your BIOS/Firmware setup? Check with ESC then F10 at power up https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-g62-300-notebook-pc-series/4247529/model/4308428/document/c03801890 .  Once you find the RAM assigned to the onboard graphics adapter, please click [edit] to tell us.   PS: 2 recalls: https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-g62-300-notebook-pc-series/4247529/model/4308428

Comment: @K7AAY actually there's no such info in the BIOS. Any info concerning memory is that it detected 4096MB.